# Trespassing an Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a control which has an Event handler. I normally used this control on many pages where I manage the raised event. But now, just once I need to put this control into another control and subsequently on a page. Is there a way to trespassing the event from the original control?

***Normal situation***

Control1 > Page

**Control1**

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;

protected virtual void OnMyEvent(EventArgs e)
{
   if(this.MyEvent != null) this.MyEvent(this, e);
}
```

**Page.aspx**

```
    <ASP:Control1 id="ctrl1" runat="server" OnMyEvent="ctrl1_MyEvent" />
```

**Page.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void ctrl1_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ....
    }
```

***Exceptional case***

**Control1 > Control2 > Page**

How can I do to re-raise the event to be managed on the page as described above? Is it possible?

I was planning to declare again on the second control an event handler and then create a method that raise the event, but I was thinking if there is another way to do this.

Comment: You'll need to raise an event in Control2's event handler for Control1's raised event.

Comment: you could register the event handler programatically in the `Page_Load` method: `ctrl2.ctrl1.OnMyEvent += ctrl1_MyEvent` (Assuming that Control2 exposes Control1 in a public field/property named `ctrl1`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating your own class, which I would call 'SomeNameEventManager'.

In your parent control, you directly subscribe / unsubscribe via this class.
And in your child control, you can raise the event by calling the method (e.g. `OnChanged`).

Example code:

```
public class SomeNameEventManager
{
ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public static event ChangedEventHandler Changed;
public static void OnChanged(EventArgs e) { Changed(this, e); }
}
```

Maybe you come up with a more dynamic way to do this.

In any case I guess, the way to go is to have **a class in the middle**.